# Is it ever explained why the Thundercats have species specific names?

Tags: names, thundercats

Our favourite feline anthropomorphic heroes all seem to have ironic names, Lion-O, Panthra, Cheetara, Tygra etc.

Is it ever explained in universe why they are named after their species and what others of their race would be called?

*<sup>obviously out of universe the naming convention makes some sense I'm interested in the in universe reasoning only</sup>*

[image: an aptly named lion]
[image: an aptly named pantha]
[image: an aptly named tiger]
[image: an aptly named cheeta]
[image: whatever the hell this is]

Comment: That always kind of bugged me about the show, but one would assume that since the show was targeted at younger kids, it was an easy naming scheme that kids could understand and identify with more easily.

Comment: Wily Kit and Wily Kat break this, as does Jaga.  In fact, most of the Thundarians who aren't the main cast from season 1 (in the old series) break this rule.  Here's a [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ThunderCats_characters) of characters from the show - most of the Thundarians aren't named after cat species.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For Snarf, at least, in-universe his real name is Osbert, but he found this embarrassing and went with his species name instead.

Quote from the episode "Feliner Part 1"

> Snarf: Who are you? How did you get here? You're a Snarf. How can that be?
>
> Snarfer: [panting] One, one question... at a time, Uncle Osbert.
>
> Snarf: Snarf!
>
> [runs over and whispers]
>
> Snarf: Sh! Don't say that. I hate that name. No one calls me Osbert. "Uncle Osbert"?
>
> Snarfer: I'm Snarfer.
>
> Snarf: Snarfer? My nephew Snarfer? That's impossible.
>
> Snarfer: It's true.
>
> Snarf: But you're just a baby... Oh... I must be getting old. That was years ago. Snarfer!
>
> [they cheer and dance around for a moment]
>
> Snarf: But never call me Osbert, OK? I'm Snarf. Just Snarf.

Comment: I would love to believe this... But do you have reference?

Comment: Edited it to add :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because not all Thunderians are Thundercats. This fact is mentioned in the second season where it is revealed that three additional Thundarians were rescued by the Ro-Bear Birbils. The Thundercats are an elite group that serves the Thunderian state and therefore their names are likely to be titles.

The other possibility is that these are largely a type of pronoun. Like "he" or "she" in humans, Thunderians may have a pair of pronouns for each subspecies. Perhaps proper names are seldom used by the Thundercats of Third Earth because there's no more than one of each species.